# entity framework not updating query after upgrading solution, provider reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework, pervasive-sql

I recently upgraded a project from VS2012 to VS2013 (it was originally created in 2010) and also upgraded the reference to one of the database providers (Pervasive.Data.Common, Pervasive.Data.SqlClient, Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.Entity) to the newer 4.0 version.  On doing this, two lines of code that were previously working no longer properly refresh the data in their queries, which are inside a using statement that is inside a function that is called each time, so there should be no long-lived objects, including both contexts and entity objects (all other statements work properly.)  The code lines at issue attempt to pull a single purchase order header tuple from the po table and a single purchase order detail line item tuple from the po_dtl table.  Placing a context.refresh call at the beginning of the code inside the using statement causes the data to properly refresh, but is a serious performance killer and won't work for production, not to mention that there should be no need to refresh, EF should be running the query anew each time the function is called.

Below is a portion of the code with the meat of the function left out for clarity.  I have also left out the po_dtl portion of the code, as the queries to determine which po_dtl tuple to use are complex and would make the code hard to read.  The line of code that is failing is noted by a comment saying so.

I have stepped through the code multiple times and have verified that

1. the context object always APPEARS to be brand new at the beginning of the statement, having no tracked entities
2. the value of poNum (the id of the po header being looked up) changes as expected
3. no matter what value poNum has, the po header that was returned by the very first execution of the query is always returned by this line of code

```
public ReceivePieceInfo(AdvanceShippingNoticePiece item, int profitUserId, Inventory.Location receiveLocation, DateTime receiveDate, string tripNumber)
{
  // LinqContextMaster.NewProfitContext provides a brand new 
  //  context each time it is called
  using (Profit.ProfitDatabase pd = LinqContextMaster.NewProfitContext)
  {
    decimal poNum = decimal.Parse(item.PurchaseOrderNumber);
    decimal poLineNum = decimal.Parse(item.PurchaseOrderLineNumber);
    IEnumerable<Profit.po> profit_pos = null;

    // THIS IS THE BROKEN CODE - no matter what poNum is, this 
    //  query always returns the very first PO that was queried
    profit_pos = pd.po.Where(po => po.po_no == poNum);

    Profit.po profit_po = null;
    if (profit_pos.Count() == 1)
      profit_po = profit_pos.Single();
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.